# Locate Ble Device GATT service recommend

Tags: android, service, location, bluetooth-lowenergy

im pretty new to android programming but I'd like to know if its possible to implement a location service to locate ble devices discovered on our app.

Im having trouble understanding the different specs for bluetooth and all examples are using the Heart Rate monitor. Its quite overwhelming considering the wide range of service and characterististics to choose from. Any suggestions ?

Also, are there any other examples that could help me with coding the profile ? Specifically showing the location of the discovered ble device if its possible.

Please do help me understand better. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am quite new to this topic, too, so please don't count on my answer.

As I understand the whole topic, you can make your peripheral BLE device send its position to the client. Therefore you might need to programm the peripheral device so that it has the Location Service enabled. Therefore you need the matching UUID I think. Then you can "Advertise" the location of your peripheral to the client (your smartphone). I still don't know though, how to do this exactly. 
Do you know about [this](https://www.bluetooth.com/develop-with-bluetooth/developer-resources-tools/app-acc-2)? It is a starter kit with software examples and explaining texts, maybe this helps.

If you found out how to deal with your problem, I would be happy to hear, even if this thread seems to be forgotten by everyone.